# How do I install Mendeley to use Anaconda python

Tags: anaconda, mendeley

I've freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 and have decided to try Anaconda. However, when I then try to install Mendeley, I get the following error:

```
mendeleydesktop depends on python; however:
  Package python is not installed.
```

I assume the issue here is that `python` is now in `~\anaconda2\bin`, instead of `\usr\bin`. I'm not certain what I should do. As I see it, I have 3 options:

1. Install a system python into `\usr\bin`, but this seems sloppy/messy
2. Put a softlink in `\usr\bin` along the lines of `ln -s python ~\anaconda2\bin\python`, but I'm worried that there might be implications to that, which I don't understand
3. Somehow tell the mendeley.deb file where the python I'm using is, but I don't know how to do this.

Are either 1 or 2 reasonable options? If not how do I implement my 3rd option, or what else should I do?

Empirically found option 2 does not work. dpkg is still looking for the installation of the python package

Comment: 1 is certainly the most reasonable option. Ubuntu itself depends on there being `/usr/bin/python` available to run scripts that manage the OS. Did Ubuntu not come with a Python there, or did you remove it?

Comment: @darthbith - My Ubuntu came with python3. Option 1 is what I ended up using. Thx for letting me know it's reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method given [here](https://coderwall.com/p/hes3ha/change-the-dependencies-of-a-deb-package) to remove the system `python` dependency in the .deb file; I tried this and mendeley seems to install as normal. Assuming your conda environment is set up correctly, it will work. I had to modify the instructions on that page slightly:

- Unpack deb: `$ ar x mendeleydesktop_1.19.4-stable_amd64.deb` (will create i.e. three files: debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz)
- Unpack control archive: `$ tar xzf control.tar.gz` (will create: postinst control)
- Fix dependencies in control (use a text editor)
- Repack control.tar.gz: `$ tar c postinst control | gzip -c > control.tar.gz`
- Repack deb: `$ ar rcs mendeleydesktop_1.19.4-stable_amd64_nopythondep.deb debian-binary control.tar.gz data.tar.gz` (order important! dpkg wouldn't be able to read the metadata of a package quickly if it had to search for where the data section ended!)